# Can I rehydrate dried chillies in bulk?

Tags: chili-peppers, dry

I have a bunch of dried chillies (chipotles, poblanos and pasillas). My preferred method for using these is to soak them in hot water for about 20 minutes, then blend them and add the paste to whatever I am cooking. This means I have to clean my blender every time I do this, which I hate.

Can I rehydrate and process these chillies in bulk, then refridgerate or freeze the paste until I need it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can refrigerate your paste, however your quality will degrade and it won't last more than a few days in the fridge. When I make pastes I usually blend 4 times what I need and freeze the leftover in chunks, then they last for weeks, even months. You could use an ice cube tray to make measured quantities to use later.

Comment: A *dedicated* ice cube tray. Don't make my mistake and reuse the one from garlic/ginger paste to make ice for drinks, even after a thorough wash

Comment: Oh god no @ChrisH, that would be interesting to say the least!

Comment: Ginger along might be OK in the right drink, but I freeze 50:50 garlic/ginger, or occasionally chilli